# Next Round:"Contestant who earns a score equal to or greater than the k-th place finisher's score

Tags: python, list

"Contestant who earns a score equal to or greater than the kth place finisher's score will advance to the next round, as long as the contestant earns a positive score..." — an excerpt from contest rules.

A total of n participants took part in the contest (n ≥ k), and you already know their scores. Calculate how many participants will advance to the next round.

Input
The first line of the input contains two integers n and k (1 ≤ k ≤ n ≤ 50) separated by a single space.

The second line contains n space-separated integers a1, a2, ..., an (0 ≤ ai ≤ 100), where ai is the score earned by the participant who got the i-th place. The given sequence is non-increasing (that is, for all I from 1 to n - 1 the following condition is fulfilled: ai ≥ ai + 1).

Output
Output the number of participants who advance to the next round.

Examples
inputCopy
8 5
10 9 8 7 7 7 5 5
outputCopy
6
inputCopy
4 2
0 0 0 0
outputCopy
0
Note
In the first example, the participant in 5th place earned 7 points. As the participant in 6th place also earned 7 points, there are 6 advancers.

In the second example, nobody got a positive score.

```
a=str(input())
b=a.split(" ")
c=str(input())
d=c.split(" ")
he=0
for k in range(0,int(b[0])):
he=he+1
print(he)
```

**This is what I tried to solve the above question in code force.
above I tried to solve it. but it gave me a runtime error.
can you help  me point out the error in my program**

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake while taking input. Read the input format again.

---

**Input:**
The **first line** of the input contains two integers `n` and `k` (1 ≤ k ≤ n ≤ 50) separated by a single space.

The **second line** contains n space-separated integers `a1, a2, ..., an` (0 ≤ ai ≤ 100), where ai is the score earned by the participant who got the i-th place. The given sequence is non-increasing (that is, for all I from 1 to n - 1 the following condition is fulfilled: ai ≥ ai + 1).

This is how you need to read input (in this example).

```py
n, k = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]
a = [int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]
```

I will explain `n, k = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]` to you.
Suppose you get input as `8, 5`.
`input()` will take it as `str`. like this `"8 5"`.
`input().split(" ")` will convert it into `list` of `str`. like this `["8", "5"]`.
then convert each `str` in `list` into `int` using `int(x) for x in input().split(" ")`.
then assign first value (`8`) to `n` and second value (`5`) to `k`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code....

```
n, k = map(int, input().split(' '))

lst = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))

lst_1 = lst[k-1]

count = 0

for i in lst:

    if i >= lst_1 and (i>0 and lst_1>0):
        count += 1


print(count)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in C++...

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;

    int a;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    {
        cin >> a;
        if (a == 0)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    int b;
    for (int i = k; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> b;
        if (b != a)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    cout << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. I believe it would greatly help everyone if you could explain why and how this answer solves the OP's problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int k=sc.nextInt();
    int[] arr=new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    
    int participants=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      if(arr[i]>=arr[k-1] && arr[i]>0)
      {
        participants+=1;
      }
    }
   
    System.out.print(participants);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. Please provide a description of how your answer solves the problem and provide references where appropriate.